What is the recommended way to support Google Sign-in on React-Native application?
I am building a React Native application with Expo+Firebase and would like to to support Google Sign-in.
According to Expo documentation, there are two options: Firebase JS SDK and React Native Firebase.
The great advantage with Firebase JS SDK is that it supports Expo Go.
Is there a way to support Google Sign-in with Firebase JS SDK?
According to this Stack Overflow question, React Native does not export the signInWIthPopup and signInWithRedirect
which are essential for the AuthN process.
Is Google Sign-in supported only with React Native Firebase?
The caveat is that React Native Firebase cannot be used with Expo Go.
I implemented the following Google Sign in method but received an error.
  async function googleSignIn() {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('profile');
    provider.addScope('email');
    await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    return getRedirectResult(auth);
  }

[TypeError: 0, _auth.signInWithRedirect is not a function (it is undefined)]

Thank you for sharing your thoughts !!
